# ¿Es posible insertar datos de tipo JSON a una base PostreSQL con SQLAlchemy? ¿Cómo?

Tags: python, json, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy

Quisiera insertar un dato de tipo JSON como tal, en la tabla PostgreSQL con SQLAlchemy en un proyecto de Flask, y no sé cómo es la forma correcta en la que se debe manejar el archivo, si lo cargo con open(), si es necesario el file.read() o hasta se requiere de un simplejson.load(file).
 Por el momento creé el campo con:

```
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

Class Tabla(db.Model):
    ...
    columna_json = db.Column(JSON)
    ...
```

Probé con:

```
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

Class Tabla(db.Model):
    ...
    columna_json = db.Column(db.Text)
    ...
```

pero me daba el error de simplejson:

```
     fp.write(chunk)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write'
```

y:

```
    return loads(fp.read(),
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Comment: un json puede ser almacenado como texto, ¿has intentado algo?

Comment: Claro pero querría saber cómo insertarlo como json, lo tengo como opción, pero sería mejor si pudiera insertarlo como json. Gracias.

Comment: creo que no me he dejado entender, un json puede ser almacenado como texto y al momento de darle un `select` , le haces un `parse` y en teoría, debería funcionar. ¿Has intentado algo? Aquí en la comunidad se valora y se presta muchísima más atención a preguntas que tienen intentos de resolución :D

Comment: :| es verdad. Ahora lo pruebo y aviso.

Comment: Toma, lectura obligatoria: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: Con sqlalchemy-json, sería un ejemplo.

Comment: elimino la pregunta? jajj

Comment: Pues, en la parte de abajo agregas lo que has hecho y serás el héroe de más usuarios que tengan la misma situación :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontré lo siguiente: https://pypi.org/project/sqlalchemy-json/ que sirve para manejar datos json en esta situación sin tener que pasarlos a texto.

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy_json import NestedMutableJson
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
import simplejson

import simplejson as json
class MyClass(Base):
    #  ...
    json_data = db.Column(NestedMutableJson)
```

De esta forma se pueden manejar los datos JSON como si se usaran con simplejson.
 Saludos y gracias por el memardo fredyfx.

Comment: un placer colaborar con la comunidad, éxitos con el desarrollo :D

Comment: Por cierto, recuerda marcar como resuelta (check verde de la izquierda) en las siguientes 24 horas aprox. Saludos